# Short story about a girl whose grandma taught her to talk to bees

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was about a simple girl. Her grandma taught her how to communicate with bees, then the next day she wanted to understand birds, then moles (I'm not sure if it was moles). A prince came by and wanted to marry her, and she ended up in a locked tower. She called the bees to sting the guards, birds to pull iron bars, and moles to dig out the ground so the tower could collapse.

I read this when I was a child ~2011. It's from a short story book that contains more stories in a thin book maybe a children's fiction.

Comment: Do you remember any other stories that were in the same book? What did the cover look like? Was it in English, was it a translation?

Comment: I don't remember it has included the story of the princess who had no heart, king with a golden touch. That's all I remembered and it was all in English. I don't remember the cover.

Comment: The story about the princess, is it the same described here http://squeezedoranges.blogspot.com/2012/04/princess-who-had-no-heart-story-summary.html?

Comment: Yes, it is part of those stories.